# How to set CMAKE static linking ( undefined reference to `dlopen' )?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, static-linking

I need to set static linking for my project.

Current state is :

```
target_link_libraries(armd
  ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY}
  ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
  rt)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0 -Wall -fmessage-length=0")
```

doesn't work on device, I need to link statically (add -static for device) but when I do

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -static")
```

I'm getting:

```
/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function `unixDlOpen':
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x3e5d4): undefined reference to `dlopen'
```

How do I set static linking for sqlite without getting this error? Or maybe my root system is missing something?

Comment: When statically linking some archives, you need to specify its dependencies (in this case libdl) yourself.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Adding dl before ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY} helped! You can provide it as answer :)

Comment: Are you really sure you want to statically link a program which is calling the dynamic linker at runtime thru `dlopen`?? Statically linking such programs is generally a bad idea.

Comment: So, without static linking my program just fails on my device, I'm not sure if there could be better way. I'm free to discuss about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When statically linking some archives, you need to specify its dependencies (in this case libdl) yourself. Be aware of that the order in which you specify the archive files on the linker command line is more important than for linking shared objects.

Comment: In addition, there are good reasons to avoid statically linking the `-ldl` library providing the dynamic runtime linker (i.e. the `dlopen` function).