# cmake linker error "undefined reference to" How to properly link the libraries in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

I have been smashing my head on my keyboard on this for hours and on similar problems for the last 3 days. I am new to cmake and trying to figure it out.

Basically i have a very simple program example for a library i am trying to use, and i am trying to make a cmake file to compile it and include all of its dependancies properly. It is day 3 and i am getting this linker error now though and i can't for the life of me figure out why.

This is what i have in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

if ( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory and run CMake from there. You may need to remove CMakeCache.txt." )
endif()

set(PROJECT_NAME HelloWorldDiscordBot)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

SET (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin
        CACHE PATH
        "Single Directory for all"
    )

SET (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin
        CACHE PATH
        "Single Directory for all"
    )

SET (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib
        CACHE PATH
        "Single Directory for all"
    )

include_directories("/home/connor/Documents/yourWaifu-sleepy-discord/")
include_directories("/home/connor/projects/HelloWorldDiscordBot/deps/")
include_directories("/home/connor/projects/HelloWorldDiscordBot/deps/include/")
include_directories("/home/connor/projects/HelloWorldDiscordBot/deps/cpr/cpr/")
include_directories("/usr/local/openssl/include")
#include_directories("/usr/include")
#include_directories("/home/connor/Documents/yourWaifu-sleepy-discord/sleepy_discord/IncludeNonexistent/")
#include_directories("/home/connor/Documents/yourWaifu-sleepy-discord/sleepy_discord/IncludeNonexistent/websocketpp/config/")
#include_directories("/home/connor/projects/HelloWorldDiscordBot/deps/lib/")

set(HelloWorldDiscordBot_sources main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HelloWorldDiscordBot_sources})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lib/libssl.a
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lib/libcrypto.a
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a)


set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

The linker error's i'm getting:

```cpp
/home/connor/projects/HelloWorldDiscordBot/build> make -j2
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/connor/projects/HelloWorldDiscordBot/build
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable bin/HelloWorldDiscordBot
../deps/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `dlopen'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `dlclose'
../deps/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_func':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x334): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x3db): undefined reference to `dlerror'
../deps/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_var':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x454): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x4fb): undefined reference to `dlerror'
../deps/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x569): undefined reference to `dlopen'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x5cb): undefined reference to `dlclose'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x603): undefined reference to `dlerror'
../deps/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x69f): undefined reference to `dladdr'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x709): undefined reference to `dlerror'
../deps/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_unload':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x762): undefined reference to `dlclose'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/connor/projects/HelloWorldDiscordBot/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::run()'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `myClientClass::myClientClass(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char)':
/home/connor/projects/HelloWorldDiscordBot/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::WebsocketppDiscordClient(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char)'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `myClientClass::~myClientClass()':
/home/connor/projects/HelloWorldDiscordBot/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::~WebsocketppDiscordClient()'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV13myClientClass[_ZTV13myClientClass]+0x10): undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::run()'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV13myClientClass[_ZTV13myClientClass]+0x1a0): undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::sleep(unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV13myClientClass[_ZTV13myClientClass]+0x1b8): undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::onError(SleepyDiscord::ErrorCode, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV13myClientClass[_ZTV13myClientClass]+0x1c0): undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::connect(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV13myClientClass[_ZTV13myClientClass]+0x1c8): undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::send(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV13myClientClass[_ZTV13myClientClass]+0x1d0): undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::disconnect(unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV13myClientClass[_ZTV13myClientClass]+0x1d8): undefined reference to `SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient::runAsync()'
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI13myClientClass[_ZTI13myClientClass]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for SleepyDiscord::WebsocketppDiscordClient'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::setUrl(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession6setUrlERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession6setUrlERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x46): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::SetUrl(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::setBody(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*)':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession7setBodyEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession7setBodyEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x46): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::SetBody(cpr::Body&&)'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::Post()':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession4PostEv[_ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession4PostEv]+0x42): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::Post()'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::Patch()':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession5PatchEv[_ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession5PatchEv]+0x42): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::Patch()'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::Delete()':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession6DeleteEv[_ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession6DeleteEv]+0x42): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::Delete()'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::Get()':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession3GetEv[_ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession3GetEv]+0x42): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::Get()'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::Put()':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession3PutEv[_ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSession3PutEv]+0x42): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::Put()'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::CPRSession()':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSessionC2Ev[_ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSessionC5Ev]+0x30): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::Session()'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::~CPRSession()':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSessionD2Ev[_ZN13SleepyDiscord10CPRSessionD5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::~Session()'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(client.cpp.o): In function `std::thread::thread<void (SleepyDiscord::BaseDiscordClient::*)(), SleepyDiscord::BaseDiscordClient*>(void (SleepyDiscord::BaseDiscordClient::*&&)(), SleepyDiscord::BaseDiscordClient*&&)':
client.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IMN13SleepyDiscord17BaseDiscordClientEFvvEJPS2_EEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IMN13SleepyDiscord17BaseDiscordClientEFvvEJPS2_EEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x93): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(cpr_session.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::setHeader(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)':
cpr_session.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::SetHeader(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(cpr_session.cpp.o): In function `SleepyDiscord::CPRSession::setMultipart(std::initializer_list<SleepyDiscord::Part> const&)':
cpr_session.cpp:(.text+0x346): undefined reference to `cpr::Multipart::Multipart(std::initializer_list<cpr::Part> const&)'
cpr_session.cpp:(.text+0x39d): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::SetMultipart(cpr::Multipart const&)'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(cpr_session.cpp.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
cpr_session.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt4pairIKS5_S5_ESt10_Select1stIS8_EN3cpr22CaseInsensitiveCompareESaIS8_EE24_M_get_insert_unique_posERS7_[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt4pairIKS5_S5_ESt10_Select1stIS8_EN3cpr22CaseInsensitiveCompareESaIS8_EE24_M_get_insert_unique_posERS7_]+0x72): undefined reference to `cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare::operator()(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
cpr_session.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt4pairIKS5_S5_ESt10_Select1stIS8_EN3cpr22CaseInsensitiveCompareESaIS8_EE24_M_get_insert_unique_posERS7_[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt4pairIKS5_S5_ESt10_Select1stIS8_EN3cpr22CaseInsensitiveCompareESaIS8_EE24_M_get_insert_unique_posERS7_]+0x12a): undefined reference to `cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare::operator()(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
../deps/lib/libsleepy_discord.a(cpr_session.cpp.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_M_insert_<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_Alloc_node>(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_Alloc_node&)':
cpr_session.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt4pairIKS5_S5_ESt10_Select1stIS8_EN3cpr22CaseInsensitiveCompareESaIS8_EE10_M_insert_IRS6_IS5_S5_ENSE_11_Alloc_nodeEEESt17_Rb_tree_iteratorIS8_EPSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSM_OT_RT0_[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt4pairIKS5_S5_ESt10_Select1stIS8_EN3cpr22CaseInsensitiveCompareESaIS8_EE10_M_insert_IRS6_IS5_S5_ENSE_11_Alloc_nodeEEESt17_Rb_tree_iteratorIS8_EPSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSM_OT_RT0_]+0x84): undefined reference to `cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare::operator()(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'bin/HelloWorldDiscordBot' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/HelloWorldDiscordBot] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloWorldDiscordBot.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Failure: Exit code 2 ***
```

[The structure of my project dependencies folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp3Qq.png)

Am i doing something wrong? I am pretty sure i have all of my dependencies in check, so i am wondering if i maybe did something dumb in my cmake file.

Comment: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7c/6b/bf/7c6bbf73f430a9c2f176484e44a61ef1.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set CMAKE static linking ( undefined reference to \`dlopen' )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009261/how-to-set-cmake-static-linking-undefined-reference-to-dlopen)